# How to create an ESDT token

Tags: javascript, multiversx

I try to create a fungible ESDT token. I am very new in MultiversX, so my understanding on creating token is: we will have to use `TokenOperationsFactory` class from [this script](https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-js-core/blob/main/src/tokenOperations/tokenOperationsFactory.ts).

First we have to use the `IConfigure` interface to instantiate the `TokenOperationsFactory`. Then we have to call the `issueFungible()`. Am I right?

If I right, then I am having these issues:

1. I don't know what will be values of parameters of `IConfigure`.
2. Is it necessary to provide values for all parameters? Because [in docs](https://docs.multiversx.com/sdk-and-tools/sdk-js/sdk-js-cookbook#preparing-a-simple-transaction) I saw a instantiation is not using all required parameters value.
3. What is the value of `esdtContractAddress` from [from this line](https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-js-core/blob/main/src/tokenOperations/tokenOperationsFactory.ts#L27)?